Trading model - apply fee at specific time point
I am currently developing an energy trading model, where I look a few hours ahead of the current time. This model is runned for several time points (but discretized into hours), namely for $\tau \in T=[1,2,3,4]$. The model considers two markets, one called x, and the other is called y, and I want to arbitrage the difference.
The model is the following
$$\text{For } \tau\in T\quad\max \sum_{t=\tau}^4 (\hat{p}^x_t - p_t^y)\Delta x_t\\
\Delta x_t \in \mathbb{R}$$
where $\hat{p}^x_t$ is the forecast of the price in market x for delivery hour t, and $p_t^y$ is the price in market y for delivery hour t (known). $\Delta x_t$ is the bought/sold amount of power to delivery hour t.
However, here comes my problem. There is a fee associated with $\Delta x_t$, namely if the sum of $\Delta t$ for all t is greater or smaller than zero. But the fee is only payed when the power is delivered. That is, the fee associated with delivery hour 1 is payed when $\tau=1$, and the fee associated with delivery hour 4 is payed when $\tau=4$.
Example: We stand at time $\tau=1$, then we maximize the objective function and make a trade such that $\Delta x_4=1$. We proceed, $\tau=1$, and trade $\Delta x_4=-1$, s.t. the sum is zero. We proceed, but the model decides not to trade (as forecast updates). This means that we do not have any fee. If the sum was different from zero, then we needed to subtract a fee from the revenue objective function.
In particular, I want the fee to be considered in the objective function, s.t. the model can decide if it is more lucrative to trade towards zero fees (and profit through out the trades), or if there is more potential in arbitraging the markets.
I hope this makes sense, thank you in advance :)

If I understood the problem correctly and the fee when you buy is $f$ and $0$ when you sell, could you add a term to the function $-f(1+\Delta x_t)/2$ that takes it into account?

Thanks for your answer, but I do not think it works, because $\Delta x_t \in \mathbb{R}$. I have updated the question :) Also, if $\Delta x_t < 0$, then the fee should also be applied.

you can use your notations/symbols as you like but as I understand suppose $F_t$ is the fee (a parameter) at time $t$, $f_t$ is a decision variable representing $F_t$ & you want it to be $\gt 0$ if a variable $0 \lt \vert \Delta x_t \vert$, then add binary $y_t$ & the constraints
$L_x y_t \le \Delta x_t \le U_xy_t$
$ f_t = y_tF_t$
where $L_x \lt 0, 0 \lt U_x$ are lower & upper bounds for $x_t$ and $f_t$ is minimized to $0$ for $\Delta x_t = 0$ if objective function minimizes this fee.
But if you wish to force $f_t =0$ when $\Delta x_t =0$ then
$\epsilon y_t + L_x(1-y_t) \le \Delta x_t \le U_xy_t - \epsilon (1-y_t)$
$f_t = F_t y_t$
where $\epsilon$ is a very small positive number $\lt$ or $\min$ of the range of possible values$ \vert \Delta x \vert$ can take, like $1e-2$.
